# Dimension of moduli space of reflexive sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking at Hartshorne's paper on stable Reflexive sheaves. He says that Maruyama has constructed a moduli space of stable torsion-free sheaves with fixed chern classes on a smooth projective variety. If $F$ is a point in the moduli space then by deformation theory, he says the dimension of tangent space at $F$ is $dim\ Ext^1(F,F)-dim\ Ext^2(F,F)$. Accordingly he computes the expected dimension of moduli space at a stable Reflexive sheaf $F$.

However I have a naive question. The class of Reflexive sheaves is contained in the class of torsion-free sheaves. So the moduli space of Reflexive sheaves should intuitively have lesser dimension isn't it? Then is the above just calculating the dimension of the moduli space of torsion-free sheaves at a point corresponding to a Reflexive sheaf?

Comment: If you consider an open dense set in a variety, their dimensions should be equal in stead of “less than”, right?

Just note that being reflexive is an open condition. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92865/is-reflexivity-an-open-condition